# Como fazer um select usando Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou tentando fazer um campo select na minha *view* e estou usando o *framework* Angular.js, só que não estou acostumado a trabalhar com ele e não estou conseguindo criar a função no *controller*. Segue abaixo o exemplo do código que tentei fazer e que não funcionou.

```
$scope.classificacaoProduto = function(idClassificacaoProduto) {
            if(idClassificacaoProduto == undefined)
                return 'Selecione';
            $http({method: 'GET', params: $scope.filtro ,url: "produtos/"+idClassificacaoProduto}).success(function(data){
                $scope.itens = data.lista;
                $scope.bigTotalItems = data.qtdRegistros;               
            });
```

A minha *view* está assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3"  class="col-sm-3 control-label "><spring:message code="produto.classificacaoProduto"/></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select
                         ng-model="produto.classificacaoProduto.nome" 
                         ng-options="item.value as item for item in [undefinded,{{produto.classificacaoProduto.nome}}]" class="form-control">                                   
                    </select>   
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o problema do teu exemplo está no `ng-options`, tente substituir por:

```
ng-options="item as item.value for item in itens"
```

A seguir tenho um exemplo que funciona em um cenário mais simplificado que você poderá se basear:

```
<div ng-app>
    <script>
        function MyController($scope) {
            $scope.colors = [
              { name: 'black', shade: 'dark' },
              { name: 'white', shade: 'light' },
              { name: 'red', shade: 'dark' },
              { name: 'blue', shade: 'dark' },
              { name: 'yellow', shade: 'light' }
            ];
        }
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <select ng-model="selectedItem"
                ng-options="color as color.name for color in colors"
                class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```